# Access custom annotation in a TestRule

Tags: java, spring, junit, annotations

Preface:

I have the following annotation and the rule initialization part of a junit test.
The goal is, to use different configuration and making the test as easy as possible to use.

```
// Annotation
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ConnectionParams {
    public String username();
    public String password() default "";
}

// Part of the test
@ConnectionParams(username = "john")
@Rule
public ConnectionTestRule ctr1 = new ConnectionTestRule();

@ConnectionParams(username = "doe", password = "secret")
@Rule
public ConnectionTestRule ctr2 = new ConnectionTestRule();
```

Now i want to access the annotation parameters in the following TestRule, but it does not find any annotation.

```
public class ConnectionTestRule implements TestRule {
    public Statement apply(Statement arg0, Description arg1) {
        if (this.getClass().isAnnotationPresent(ConnectionParams.class)) {
            ... // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

How can i access the annotation within the TestRule?

Answer (score -1):

Your application is incorrect.

Apply custom annotation on class level and not on the way you have done it.

```
// Apply on class instead
@ConnectionParams(username = "john")
public class ConnectionTestRule {....
```

Then your code should work,

```
public class ConnectionTestRule implements TestRule {
    public Statement apply(Statement arg0, Description arg1) {
      //get annotation from current (this) class
      if (this.getClass().isAnnotationPresent(ConnectionParams.class)) {
        ... // do stuff
      }
    }
}
```

EDIT : After updated question.

You need to get first the field using reflection so that you will find each ConnectionTestRule object you created and get from it your annotation to get your required configuration.

```
for(Field field : class_in_which_object_created.getDeclaredFields()){
      Class type = field.getType();
      String name = field.getName();
      //it will get annotations from each of your 
      //public ConnectionTestRule ctr1 = new ConnectionTestRule();
      //public ConnectionTestRule ctr2 = new ConnectionTestRule();
      Annotation[] annotations = field.getDeclaredAnnotations();
      /*
       *
       *once you get your @ConnectionParams then pass it respective tests
       *
       */
}
```

Comment: i updated the question, my goal is, to run tests with different configurations

Comment: I have updated answer. You need to first find annotation from your objects / fields and then get annotations from them and finally pass the configurations to your tests

Comment: The TestRule does not know where it will be used, so your suggested "class_in_which_object_created.getDeclaredFields()" will not work out.

Comment: Don't you know in which class this will be created?
@ConnectionParams(username = "john")
@Rule
public ConnectionTestRule ctr1 = new ConnectionTestRule();

Comment: Exactly, i will not know who will use the rule to establish a connection.

Comment: @SandroKoch that won't be possible I suppose what you are trying to achieve. Because annotation will be found in executing object or instance. In your case you want to get annotation in your ConnectionTestRule but those are defined on objects of ConnectionTestRule.